# We cannot auto-play sound on a webpage without client interaction: How Skype for web gets around this requirement?

Tags: javascript, audio, permissions, notifications

I think all or most browsers do not let the server or even a client JavaScript code cause the automatic playing of a sound/audio.
Testing Chrome, the only way I found to play a sound automatically without any client interaction every time was that the client goes to the Chrome settings one time and manually adds a specific website (https//: example.com:443) and allows the sound from that website (permanently unless the browser settings are wiped out or manually removed). Also, allowing all the websites to play sound generally does not have the same effect of being specific in the settings.

I found that permission for push notifications is not required for this purpose. I banned [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) from sending push notifications; nevertheless, upon allowing sound manually in the settings, as I mentioned above, auto-play without client interaction was still possible.

**How is that Skype for the web can get around this?**
Skype can send its famous Skype ringtone to the client using the web version when someone from the contact list or an absolute stranger wants to call from another computer/web browser or from, a native phone app, or a desktop app (mac or windows):

**https://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-web/**

Comment: Are you sure that you don't click anything on the website before someone calls you?

Comment: Certainly, I don't go to the settings and give permissions (when using Skype for the web). In another Stackoverflow, someone guarantees that it is impossible to use JavaScript to change that setting even with client permission. However, we are talking about Skype for the web here.

Comment: Youtube also plays without user's interaction. It's just that chrome lets some sites do that

Comment: You're suggesting that Opera, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, all made exceptions for Skype, and YouTube. Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because of [Media Engagement Index](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#media-engagement-index)

---

[From the chrome's post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#new-behaviors)

Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

- The user has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
- On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
- The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.

---

[Media Engagement Index](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#media-engagement-index)

The Media Engagement Index (MEI) measures an individual's propensity to consume media on a site. Chrome's approach is a ratio of visits to significant media playback events per origin

- Consumption of the media (audio/video) must be greater than seven seconds.
- Audio must be present and unmuted.
- The tab with the video is active.
- Size of the video (in px) must be greater than 200x140.

From that, Chrome calculates a media engagement score, which is highest on sites where media is played on a regular basis. When it is high enough, media is allowed to autoplay on desktop only.

---

That's why some sites like youtube or skype for web can play sounds without prior user's interaction

This page is very useful in chrome `about://media-engagement`